# Linear transformation/ Image equals kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to come up with an example of a vector space $V$ and a linear map $f\in \textrm{Hom}\,\left ( V,V \right )$ such that $\textrm{Im}\,f = \ker f$. Any help please?

- Also, it is asked that if such a linear map $f$ is defined as above on a vector space $V$, what can we say about $\dim V$? My answer for this second part is: it is known that $\dim V = \dim \ker f  + \dim (\textrm{Im}\, f)=2\cdot\dim \ker f=2\cdot\dim (\textrm{Im}\, f)$. Is that what it is meant by the question?

Comment: Specifically, you can say that the dimension of $V$ must be either infinite or finite and even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the dimension of $V$  is finite it  must be $0$ or an even number $N$.
Then taking a basis $B$ of $V$ you can define $T$  for the $N/2$ first vectors of $V$ as $0$
and  each of the rest you can send one one to the first $N/2$ vectors of $B$.
Then, taking away the zero vectors  you got a generator (and basis) of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ with $N/2$ vectors, that is also a basis of $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2 $ and define $f$ by its action on the basis vectors:
$$ i \mapsto j $$
$$ j \mapsto 0 $$

Then $\operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{Ker}(f)$.